# Webpage translator using paid google translate api?

Tags: google-translate

Is there a way to use the google automatic webpage translator (or something equivalent) with the paid google-translate api?

From the paid google-translate api docs, it seems that it can only do "words" not pages, so I'd have to write my own automatic dom parser+text replacement system

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Cloud Translate API is not meant to translate webpages. As you already noticed, it is a dynamic translation of source text from the source language to a target language (such as French to English). Language detection is also available in cases where the source language is unknown.